# Change the class of a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, class, oop

Is it possible to change the class of a Javascript variable ?

Let's say I have 2 classes :

```
class A {
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
  }
}

class B {
  constructor(x, y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
  }
}
```

And one variable of type A

```
let a = new A(20);
```

How coulid I change the type of `a` such that

```
(a instanceof B)
```

return true and not false ?

EDIT : I would like to know to solve a specific problem. I have a tree structure where each node of the tree is a Javascript object of class A or B (actually I have more class which all inherit from a base class but let's keep it simple).
At some point, I would like to transform a node A into a node B. But I only have access to the node itself, not the parent nodes. So I would like to make a method inside the class A which transform the instanciated variable into an object of class B.

Comment: Is this pure curiosity or a concrete problem you're trying to solve? (in which case, tell us more about it).

Comment: I am trying to solve a specific problem. I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make one of the classes extend the other?

```js
class B {
  constructor(x, y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
  }
}
class A extends B {
  constructor(x) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
  }
}



let a = new A(20);
console.log(a instanceof B);
```

Or set the prototype manually and return an object from A (weird):

```js
class B {
  constructor(x, y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
  }
}
class A {
  constructor(x) {
    const instance = Object.create(B.prototype);
    instance.x = x;
    return instance;
  }
}



let a = new A(20);
console.log(a instanceof B);
```

Or do it outside (extremely weird, don't do this):

```js
class B {
  constructor(x, y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
  }
}
class A {
  constructor(x) {
    this.x = x;
  }
}



let a = new A(20);
Object.setPrototypeOf(a, B.prototype);
console.log(a instanceof B);
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to your update, one possible solution would be to employ a `Pointer` object. A `Pointer` is a transparent proxy that redirects every "set" and "get" operation to its `target`. Additionally, it provides a special property (`$$$` in this example) that allows to change the target without changing the pointer itself. This way, you can replace an object "in place", given only a direct reference to it.

For the rest of the application, `Pointer(x)` looks and behaves exactly like `x`.

Example:

```js
let Pointer = target => new Proxy({}, {
    getPrototypeOf() {
        return Reflect.getPrototypeOf(target)
    },
    get(_, p) {
        return Reflect.get(target, p)
    },
    set(_, p, v) {
        if (p === '$$$')
            return target = v
        return Reflect.set(target, p, v)
    }
})

//

class A {
    hello() {
        return 'aaa'
    }
}

class B {
    hello() {
        return 'BBB'
    }
}

let objects = [
    Pointer(new A),
    Pointer(new A),
    Pointer(new A),
    Pointer(new A),
]

function setObjectToB(obj) {
    obj.$$$ = new B
}

console.log(...objects.map(x => x.hello()))
console.log(objects[2] instanceof A)

setObjectToB(objects[2])

console.log(...objects.map(x => x.hello()))
console.log(objects[2] instanceof B)
```